# hex charecter "1f40" appering in top of web pages in internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11

one of my web project this particular issue is occurring . i am getting no clue to resolve it .
issue :
it is working fine in local server in all browsers .
but when i deploy it in remote server   (FreeBSD12.0-RELEASE-p13 GENERIC amd64) then also it is working normally in all except internet explorer .

in IE the web page is appearing with hexadecimal code in top of page :    1f40

[image]

and in bottom code is like "0" or 3f 0 varying time to time machine to machine ..

[image]

Can one please help me to resolve this issue ? i have no clue for this kind of behavior expecting assuming it is related to mime / enc-type but cant get confirmed . is their any solution ?

Comment: Provide website url also.

Comment: Try to use F12 developer tools DOM Explorer to check which elements will display these characters. Besides, can you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the problem? it might be easier for us to narrow down the problem.